# Communicating backend by Front End other than http

Tags: javascript, php, html, web-services, http

The most common method by which Front End(Javascript, html) can communicate with backend technologies(.net, php, nodejs) is an **http Request**

**Example:**

```
HTTP::Request->new(
  GET => $url,
  HTTP::Headers->new(Header => Value,...),
)
```

I was wondering of any other way **other than** http to communicate with the backend. Can anyone suggest any method with links?

Comment: tcp, https, ftp etc.

Comment: Read this article http://html5doctor.com/methods-of-communication/

Comment: Care to share code for tcp?

Comment: Websockets for example. Check out socket.io just to name one solution

Comment: What do you mean by "front-end"? Web browser or any software? Bittorrent for example uses its own protocol

Comment: I mean JS client code ... rendered and parsed by browser while execution.

Answer (score 1):

HTTP is the protocol that how web-clients and web-server 
communicates.

There are many alternatives than http. It simply depends on what you are trying to do.

Most often, the choice of protocol is given by the existing server one wishes to connect to. If you write your own client *and* server, feel free to develop and implement your own protocol.

Other transfer protocols are like:

- FTP: File Transfer Protocol
- SMTP: Simple Mail Transfer Protocol
- TFTP: Trivial File Transfer Protocol
- SFTP: Simple FTP
- NNTP: Network News Transfer Protocol